# Get printer to be wireless without a Wi-Fi button

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

- **Printer**: Canon Pixma G2000
- **Router**: GX Titanium 2122A (Some trash that came with the connection - **No USB port**)
- **Connection**: Type A USB(M) connector >>USB Type A (F) - RJ45 (F) << Cat 8 >> LAN port on router.

All the computers are using Windows and all the phones are Android.
This printer model doesn't have a "Wi-Fi button" that's shown in some support blogs.

I need to make the printer wireless. I used to do it by hooking it up to a computer and sharing it. But since I don't want to leave a PC on just for this, I'd like only the printer to be online.

So far I've tried looking it up by searching for printers through control panel. Then by changing the port in printer properties to STD TCP/IP port and disabling the bidrectional option. Then changed some router settings that I don't even remember now, based on the advice from some tech blogs.

What am I overlooking here?

Secondly, (this is not as important), is it possible to find this wirelessly shared printer on a pc that is wired to the same router? (basically the PC connected to the next LAN slot on the router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do I understand correctly - you're connecting some random USB-Ethernet adapter to the printer, and wire from there to the router? Does the printer natively support Ethernet connection over USB port?

As is I doubt this has any chance of succeeding. The reason is standards and protocols - Ethernet works on 802.3, USB doesn't. It's like you tried to instruct a swahili speaker over phone how to bake bread... if you don't have a common protocol (language) it's not going to happen.

When you connect this kind of device to a computer, you have to install a driver (or Windows might do it for you). But I don't know any way of installing a USB network card driver to a printer.

What you need is a USB (or Wireless) Print Server. That's a small, fairly inexpensive piece of hardware designed for exactly this - sharing USB printers over the network. You connect USB to printer, wire to the router, and after a while you will see an available network printer.

Comment: It is probably more cost effective (and skill-appropriate) to just buy a new printer than to configure a USB print server…

Comment: LOL :-D Dunno, never configured a consumer-grade print server :-D Pricewise... Amazon does sell low-end wired print servers for under 40 euros, while even cheapest wireless printers tend to cost double that - unless you happen on on a sale, of course. In which case you're often buying the manufacturers out-of-production leftovers :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried the adapter based on an advice from a guy on reddit. One of the many things I've tried. Apparently what you said makes more sense. Does it make more sense to buy a wireless printer or a print server?

Comment: That's a question I have to leave to you. I'd go for a wired print server shared through the router, but that's based on my personal experience and situation. EU laws state minimum 14 days return time for all purchases, so I could even go and buy both, test them at home, keep whatever suits me better and return the other one. But EU laws obviously don't apply worldwide.

Comment: Understood. Much appreciated. If you don't mind me asking one more thing, if the usb to rj45 doesn't make sense then why does the adapter exist? What else could I possibly do with it?

Comment: Think about modern slimline laptops. They come without Ethernet ports, but you might need a wired connection, maybe WiFi has too much interference to be stable or something. Get one of those adapters, install the driver and you're good to go :-)

Comment: Please do note what @hdhondt says. I wouldn't use as strong expression as "most certainly NOT work", but as I said I have no experience with consumer-grade devices, I just know they exist. You might need to shop around to find one that's compatible with your printer. A new wireless printer does avoid those issues, but they do present their own.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual for your specified printer, it is not a wireless printer. This leaves only one option remaining, as your router does not have USB utility. Wireless print servers are effectively replacements for the computer you don't want to have connected and leave on.

It's a device connected to power (obviously) and to your printer via the standard USB connection. The device is configured to communicate with your network (read and follow all label directions) which will then allow the printer to appear when you use the control panel "search for printers" option.

Amazon has many options with prices a few dollars either side of US$40 that will likely work for you.

Comment: This is an option, another one is to replace the printer with one that has Wireless capability build in, given the price of a print server vs an actual printer. Also, a wired printserver is also an option and still allows one to print wirelessly. The client connects through wireless to the router and the router does the rest. A wired print-server is much cheaper.

Comment: With GDI printers like this one, a printserver will only work if it specifically supports the printer. Unless the printer is listed in the printserver's compatibility list, it will almost certainly NOT work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!